# How to get and set the location of cursor?

Tags: c++, winforms, cursor

I am working on a windows forms application in c++.Currently I am able to display cursor location relative to forms application.If cursor moves out of the application boundary it displays the point at which cursor moved out of the application.But, I want to get the cursor location on the entire screen ,not just within the application boundaries and I want location relative to screen co-ordinates but not  application's.Any suggestions on how i can achieve my goal?

Comment: Look into the  `GetCursorPos` function to map to window coordinates.

Comment: GetCursorPos is giving cursor location in screen co-ordinates only when my cursor is on application.When it is out of application bounds,the value isn't changing!

Comment: You could try `ScreenToClient`; sorry I am not able to test it out at the moment to clarify.